# jQuery starts another function and I don't want it

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8cuz/

jQuery code:

```
$('.list').hide();
$('.close').hide();
var widthVal = false;
$('#left').click(function(){
    if(widthVal == false){
    $('#middle').hide('fade', 300);
    $('#right').hide('fade', 300, function(){
    $('#left').find('.list').show();
    $('#left').find('.close').show();
    $('#left').animate({
    width: "96%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000 );
    });
    widthVal == true;
    }
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({
    width: "30%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500 );
    widthVal == false;
    $('#middle').show();
    $('#right').show();
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.close').hide();
});
```

When I click the `#left` div, it works ok, but when I click `X`, it should hide the details, hide the `X`, show the `#middle` and the `#right` tags and set the width to 30%. It does this, but then it comes back to 96% width. I don't know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your click event is propagating up the DOM and triggering the click event on the left div again. Use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent this. Just change the close code to:

```
$('.close').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().animate({
        width: "30%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500);
    widthVal == false;
    $('#middle').show();
    $('#right').show();
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.close').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z8cuz/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Always `return false` from your click handlers. Otherwise the event bubbles up in the DOM and that's why `$('#left').click` is also triggered

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({
    width: "30%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500 );
    widthVal == false;
    $('#middle').show();
    $('#right').show();
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.close').hide();
    return false;
});
```